# Merge multiple json objects

Tags: javascript, json

I am working currently on javascript project. In my project i have two json array like:

```
var one = [{
"dps": {
        "1516624200": 0.03333333333333333,
        "1516624800": 0.88,
        "1516625400": 0.0,
        "1516626000": 0.0,
        "1516626600": 0.0,
        "1516627200": -0.012962962962963048,
        "1516627800": -0.022390572390572364,
        "1516628400": 20.37605723905724,
        "1516629000": 80.06746296296296,
        "1516629600": 94.12977777777778,
        "1516630200": 94.11733333333332,
        "1516630800": 94.1302777777778,
        "1516631400": 94.19999999999995
        }
}]  

var two = [{
"dps": {
        "1516624200": 0.2,
        "1516624800": 0.95,
        "1516625400": 0.0,
        "1516626000": 0.0,
        "1516626600": 0.0,
        "1516627200": -0.55,
        "1516627800": -0.6,
        "1516628400": 20.77,
        "1516629000": 8296296296,
        "1516629600": 99,
        "1516630200": 99,
        "1516630800": 55,
        "1516631400": 94.19999999999995
        }
}]
```

I want to merge these two array and finaloutput should be like these type of array

```
[1516624200,0.03333333333333333,0.2],[1516624800,0.88,0.0]
```

I am using like:

```
 var graphData = [];
    var getValue = data[0].dps;
    var getVal = data[1].dps;
    for(var i in getVal){
        for(j in getVal){
            graphData.push([new Date(i*1000),getVal[i],getVal[i]])
        }
    }
```

This give me wrong values. Please help.

Comment: `JSON` is a string not an object. If you want to make a JSON String to an object you have to call `JSON.parse(myJSONstring)`

Comment: You don't need the inner loop

Answer (score 3):

Use `map`

```
var output = Object.keys(one[0].dps).map( s => [ s, one[0].dps[s], two[0].dps[s] ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

`try this`

```
var graphData = [];
for (let obj of one[0].dps) {
graphData.push(obj);
}
for (let obj of two[0].dps){
graphData.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of what your code does, what the output looks like, why is it better than the OP's code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var graphData = [];
var newGraphDataValue = [];
var oneDps = one[0].dps;
var twoDps = two[0].dps;

Object.keys(oneDps).forEach(function(oneDpsKey){
    newGraphDataValue = [oneDpsKey, oneDps[oneDpsKey]];
    Object.keys(twoDps).forEach(function(twoDpsKey){
    if (twoDpsKey === oneDpsKey) {
        newGraphDataValue.push(twoDps[twoDpsKey]);
    }
  });
  graphData.push(newGraphDataValue);
});

console.log('Result: ', graphData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor modification to your code:

```
  var graphData = [], i, j, d;

  var getValue = one[0].dps;
  var getVal = two[0].dps;
  for(i in getValue){
    for(j in getVal){
      d = new Date(i*1000);
      graphData.push([d.getTime(),getValue[i], getVal[j]]);
    }
  }
  console.log(graphData);
```

Got the results like the following:

```
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 0.2]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 0.95]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 0]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 0]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 0]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, -0.55]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, -0.6]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 20.77]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 8296296296]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 99]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 99]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 55]
(3) [1516624200000, 0.03333333333333333, 94.19999999999995]
(3) [1516624800000, 0.88, 0.2]
...
```